# Oracle Time Range Query

Tags: oracle, date, range

I need to write a query which will do a date lookup by the most completed quarter hour.

So, if the current time is 5:35, then the criteria would be 5:15 - 5:30.   If the time is 5:46, then 5:30 - 5:45, if the time is 6:02, then 5:45 - 6:00.

Not sure how to easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
with cqh (dt) as (
  select trunc(sysdate, 'hh') + 
         trunc(extract(minute from systimestamp) / 15) * interval '15' minute
  from   dual
)
select [_data_] from [_your_table_] cross join cqh
where  [_date_column_] >= cqh.dt - interval '15' minute
  and  [_date_column_] <  cqh.dt
;
```

The subquery calculates the most recently completed quarter-hour. It first truncates `SYSDATE` to the beginning of the current hour. Then we add a multiple of 15 minutes - the multiplier is 0, 1, 2 or 3, depending on the minute component of `SYSDATE`. Alas, `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ...)` only works on timestamps, so I had to use `SYSTIMESTAMP` there instead of `SYSDATE`, but other than that, the computation should be pretty obvious.

Then cross-join whatever else gives you "the data" to this small helper view, to use the `DT` value calculated in it.